# Using forked project in Podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods, fork

I am trying to use a forked project inside the Podfile but so far I am facing this error:

```
Unable to find a specification for 'Mussel'
```

This is the line for the pod in my Podfile:

```
pod 'Mussel', :git => 'https://github.com/HarperDog/Mussel.git', :commit => '01fcd22ee11c6f172c5218d9c1f81b5c5b62a13d'
```

And this is the original git url of the project: https://github.com/UrbanCompass/Mussel

What I have tried so far:

```
pod repo update
pod install
pod update
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I believe cocoapods podspecs need to be in the format `xxx.podspec`. The linked library is `xxx.podspec.erb` - perhaps it can't find the specification because it's named incorrectly.

It also looks like the forked library never updated the podspec, as it looks like it's pointing to a built binary on the original GitHub.

```
s.homepage                    = "https://github.com/UrbanCompass/Mussel"
s.license                     = { type: 'MIT' }
s.author                      = "Compass"
s.source                      = { :http => "#{s.homepage}/releases/download/#{s.version}/release.zip" }
```

You're going to have to either fork it yourself and fix all of these, or possibly try Swift Package Manager. I'd say it's likely the person who forked it only wanted it for their needs and didn't bother updating all the dependency managers.